# Движение объекта Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

помогите разобраться. Мне нужно, чтобы объект двигался в то место куда было осуществлено нажатие на экран, вместо этого объект летит куда ему вздумается. Что я делаю не так?

```
public class MoveHeroInMap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1f;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    public void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }  

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 curPos = rb.position;
        float hInput = Input.GetTouch(0).position.x;
        float vInput = Input.GetTouch(0).position.y;

        Vector2 inputVector = new Vector2 (hInput, vInput);
        inputVector = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(inputVector, 1);

        Vector2 movement = inputVector * speed;
        Vector2 newPos = curPos + movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        rb.MovePosition(newPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input.GetTouch(0)` возвращает позицию относительно экрана. Вам нужно конвертировать её используя метод [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)